# from an array of two columns, how to replace file names that match the second column with entries from the first column?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of files with the names: string1sth, string2sth, string3sth ... and so on. They are not numbered; the numbering is just an example.
And I have a file of two columns of this format:

```
15  string1
14  string2
4a  string3
4b  string4
11  string5
18  string6
12  string7
2   string8
10  string9
1   string10
8   string11
16a string12
```

and so on.

The question is: I want to rename the files (or make new files) but using entries from column1 instead of 2; that is replace file names starting with string1, string2... etc by 15, 14, ... etc.

Any thoughts on how to do this in bash?

Comment: thanks. I will make sure to follow this ...

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
while read nn on
do
  mv "$on"* $nn
done < mapping.txt
```